# Meteor SimpleSchema does not throw error

Tags: validation, meteor, simple-schema

I'm trying to implement checks in Meteor method, but facing some strange behavior of SimpleSchema package (i'm using latest one which is 1.3.3 at the moment);

From the Docs:

> Call mySimpleSchema.validate(doc) to validate doc against the schema and throw a ValidationError if invalid. This is like check(doc, mySimpleSchema) but without the check dependency and with the ability to pass full schema error details back to a callback on the client.

I defining a simple Schema like this:

```
var mySchema = new SimpleSchema({ name: {type: String} });

var invalidDoc = { name: 123 };
```

However mySchema object does not have "validate" method. I can only call validation using

`mySchema.namedContext().validate(invalidDoc);`

This method return false, but didn't throw any exception.
The only way to go about I found so far is to call Meteor "check" function like this:
`check(invaidDoc, mySchema)` And this does work as expected.

So, my question is: how to perform checking of object in Meteor method context, without using check();

```
Meteor.methods({
  'myMethod'(someObject) {

    var schema = new SimpleSchema({
        name: { type: String }
    });

    schema.namedContext().validate(someObject); //DOES NOT THROW!

    console.log('This should not be here!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature [has apparently been added in version 1.4.0](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/commit/dfe31f9067c0391832972a89890704ff3b0ae809#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R619) of the SimpleSchema package, so it is not available yet in v1.3.3. I guess you will have to use `check()` until 1.4.0 hits atmosphere!

Comment: Thank you so much! I added `aldeed:simple-schema@1.4.0` and it works like a charm!